# How to export a local function within an Express router.get() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller, module.exports

I wish to export a local function using `module.exports = { router, functionName }` but I am struggling to do so at the moment.
My code is shown below - I want to know how to export the controller 'checkUserLoginCredentials'.

```
router.get('/', async function checkUserLoginCredentials(req, res) {
    //Controller code handling user login
});
```

I wish to export the controller to be used in unit tests but as the controller is a local function I cannot simply place it in `module.exports` and then import it into my test file using `const { checkUserLoginCredentials } = require('path')` . Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: `router.get("/", checkUserLoginCredentials)`, then declare the function before.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the controller into its own file, then using `require("./path/to/controller")` to use it in both routing as well as unit testing.